# Changing nameservers from Weebly to another provider for email, will it affect my site?

Tags: dns, nameserver, weebly

I have a Weebly site and I wan't a free custom domain email. There is an option of G Suite that's like $4/m but I found a Migadu which is free. The thing is that Migadu wants me to change the name servers of my website which I can, but I don't know how it will affect the site. Will I lose anything?

Comment: Impossible to say. Who is s your current DNS provider? Why do the y want you to change? Does Weebly have any requirements? There is not enough information here to answer your question. Can you add actionable info? Cheers!!

Comment: @Blackmagyk In general, changing nameservers does not affect a website as long as the same DNS records are maintained, which should be the case [here](https://www.migadu.com/en/guides/from_scratch.html#dns_configure).  That is how many CDN's also work - they first scan your current DNS records and import in the same values. In this case, they'll likely change or add an `MX` record so you can receive email on their servers.

Comment: You can usually switch email providers just by changing the MX records.   You shouldn't need to change the NS records.   While Migadu recommends their "simple DNS" option with them as the name server, they also support "External DNS": https://www.migadu.com/en/guides/from_scratch.html#dns_profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site will go down if you change the Name Servers.

Ask Migadu if they have any MX records that you can apply to the domain instead.  That is really all that is needed to transfer the email hosting to another provider.  If they don't, you may want to seek out another provider.

Answer (score 1):

Migadu hosts only email, so you can leave your site with your current web hosting provider or move to another.  Being an email hoster, they should only be asking you to change your email servers.  Your DNS servers are maintained by your website hosting provider.  You will have 2 providers not 1. Migadu will do all the email, so it will read me@mydomain.xxx.  And your web hosting provider will handle all traffic to and from your web site mydomain.xxx.

Migadu should ask you to change your mail servers:  SMTP, IPOP (if applicable), incoming/outgoing.  And of course you will need to change any mailto's on your site to reflect your new mail servers (mailto:me@mydomain.xxx).

Your domain name servers (DNS) should not change because that routes traffic to your website itself.  Those need to point to your web hosting provider.

Comment: The OP is correct in that Migadu does request users to change their nameservers, as can be seen in their setup guide [here](https://www.migadu.com/en/guides/from_scratch.html#dns_configure). In many cases with email hosting services, what you wrote would be correct, but just not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://hc.weebly.com/hc/en-us/articles/201740093-How-Can-I-Change-My-Site-s-Address-or-Domain-Name-
The instruction might be helpful. You can avoid this problem with WordPress or Mobirise for example. You can change the domain in the app very easy.

Comment: When I click on that link it asks me to log in and when I can't it takes me to a 404 page.  Can you find an accessible link or tell us more about what the linked page says?